# Prevent prompting for PEM passphrase

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, interrupt

I am building a Qt-based application that will communicate through https with a webserver. The setup should allow client-authentication with a local certificate and private key. The application must run *without any user interaction*.

Now I have a problem when the private key file is protected by a passphrase:
OpenSSL will prompt for a password, **blocking the whole application!**

The openSSL API allows to pass a callback for getting the passphrase, but this is not accessible though the Qt Wrapper. Is there another way to prevent openSSL from prompting for a password? Or can this somehow be interrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution:

OpenSSL will only prompt for a password, when none is specified in the decode function. As Richard Moore pointed out in his answer, `QSslKey` has a constructor where you can pass the passphrase.

As long as an non-empty string is passed here, OpenSSL won't prompt for a password. Plus: If the key is not protected, *the password is ignored*. Therefore, I simply make sure that a non-empty string is passed, so this is my solution:

```
// Never use empty PWD, as this blocks. (Use null-string)
// PLUS: setting a password for a non-protected key still correctly loads the key!
QByteArray thePwd = pwd.isEmpty() ? QByteArray("\0", 1) : pwd.toUtf8();

// Try all encodings
QList<QSslKey> keys = QList<QSslKey>()
    << QSslKey( theKey, QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, QSsl::PrivateKey, thePwd )
    << QSslKey( theKey, QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Der, QSsl::PrivateKey, thePwd )
    << QSslKey( theKey, QSsl::Dsa, QSsl::Pem, QSsl::PrivateKey, thePwd )
    << QSslKey( theKey, QSsl::Dsa, QSsl::Der, QSsl::PrivateKey, thePwd );

// Find a valid encoding
foreach ( QSslKey k, keys ) {
    if ( !k.isNull() ) {
        ret = k;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On looking at the [online documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qsslsocket.html), I don't see any callback options when decrypting the private key.

The simplest way is to make the private key password-free. Here's how you could do it (assuming you have password-protected RSA keys):

`openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -out newPrivateKey.pem`

Here `privateKey.pem` is password protected but `newPrivateKey.pem` is not. Note that while this means the private key is unprotected, this is a common technique to do uninterrupted SSL communication (even used in `stunnel` for instance). The assumption is that the private key is stored in a directory which has restricted permissions and is protected by the operating system access policy.

The harder way is to write your application by directly linking with OpenSSL instead of going through the wrapper. That way, you have a fine-grained control on the password callbacks.

Comment: Yes, the use of unprotected PK would solve my problem. While this is common for web-servers, but my application is on the client side and I cannot impose a requirement that PK file must not be protected...

Comment: How is the solution that you posted going to work if the private key is indeed protected? It will assume that the ``thePwd`` is the password and will try to decrypt the private key and will fail.

Comment: It will not prompt for the passphrase, so the process will not be blocked. The key cannot be used in such a case, but the process can react on this situation and proceed, even only to gracefully shut down. Otherwise I'd have a BG-Process that is forever blocked on I/O

Comment: If the client you are writing is a general purpose client, then this might not be the most attractive option. But, since you are the app  developer, it's your call. In my app, we obfuscate the password in the environment and have the callback retrieve, unobfuscate and use it. This helps in building unattended client/server apps (while keeping the private key protected). This is not as strong as the user manually entering the password, but comes very close to that as the only way someone can hijack the password is to hijack the user's terminal which, in most practical cases, is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the password when you construct the QSslKey. The constructor takes a passphrase which will be used to decrypt the key, see the docs at the link below:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsslkey.html#QSslKey-2

Comment: I understand that I can pass the password in the constructor. But I'm facing problems when there is no password configured for my application, yet the file is protected. In this case, there is nothing to pass, and the app blocks